# Android API for Keyboard Dynamics

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

I'm considering using the Android keyboard API for making an app requiring keyboard dynamics information.

Does it give me the kind of control and precision that is required for something like this? I took a look at [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html) and it seems like it should work.

The kind of details I will require will be mostly

- time lapsed between consecutive key presses
- exact time when a down event happens and an up event happens

Other suggestions, as well as Anything else you can tell me about this, are also welcome!

Comment: What constitutes "keyboard dynamics information"?

Comment: The two things I mentioned in bullet points constitute keyboard dynamics information.
Keyboard dynamics is a behavioral biometric that tries to identify the user based on his/her typing style. [Read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_dynamics)

Answer (score 0):

In general, this seems a doable thing. You can certainly capture the time at which a keyboard event is fired (including press and release), perhaps with [`System.currentTimeMillis`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29). While generally there is only a very small gap between when a key is pressed and the event firing this can be exacerbated by high CPU load. I'm not sure what your exact application is, but if it is centered around authentication, you might consider recording the text and all of this timing information first for the entire input before processing it (as opposed to "real-time").

Comment: Yeah it is for authentication. I do plan to record the text as well, instead of doing it real-time. Thanks :)